# Custom Component in Video.js

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I'm trying to make video plaver with custom controls. I have code like:

```
var video = videojs(video.id, {
    controls: true,
    autoplay: false,
    controlBar: {
        children: [
            ...
        ]
    }
});
```

and it's generating DOM like:

```
<div class="video-js">
    <video></video>
    <div class="vjs-poster"></div>
    <div class="vjs-text-track-display"></div>
    <div class="vjs-loading-spinner"></div>
    <button class="vjs-big-play-button"></button>
    <div class="vjs-control-bar"></div>
    <div class="vjs-error-display"></div>
    <div class="vjs-modal-dialog"></div>    
</div>
```

Between `<video></video>` and `<div class="vjs-poster"></div>` I want custom div, e.g. `<div class="overlay"></div>`.

Is there a possibility to do it using video.js components? Or do I have to use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`? I read video.js docs, I think there is a possibility to do this, but I have no idea how. Nothing works.

Comment: If you are just trying to add, drop, or re-order the controls, you can do that entirely via CSS.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808513/how-to-change-layout-of-controls-in-video-js/41990551#41990551

Answer (score 0):

Wrote up something that explains how to maneuver adding custom components to Video.js, it can be quite confusing

Hope this helps!

https://nikushx.com/blog/2019/05/21/creating-custom-components-with-video-js/